# Building wheel for cryptacular failed

Tags: python-wheel

Can anybody find me a way to install this package, because all the solutions that i retrieved by searching were suitable for the specified package in the question.

I have Win.10 and i use Pycharm for ide.
The problem seems to be in a package named cryptacular
I tried already to download and install manually but it didn't work.

'''

```
Collecting pyshop
  Using cached pyshop-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docutils
  Using cached docutils-0.18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (570 kB)
Collecting pyramid-filterwarnings
  Using cached pyramid_filterwarnings-0.4.tar.gz (3.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting zope.sqlalchemy
  Using cached zope.sqlalchemy-1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting pyramid-tm
  Using cached pyramid_tm-2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting pyramid-jinja2
  Using cached pyramid_jinja2-2.10-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
Collecting pyramid-rpc
  Using cached pyramid_rpc-0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting cryptacular
  Using cached cryptacular-1.6.2.tar.gz (75 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\meir israeli\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from pyshop) (58.1.0)
Collecting SQLAlchemy
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.4.36-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting pyramid>=1.5
  Using cached pyramid-2.0-py3-none-any.whl (246 kB)
Collecting plaster
  Using cached plaster-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting zope.deprecation>=3.5.0
  Using cached zope.deprecation-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting webob>=1.8.3
  Using cached WebOb-1.8.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114 kB)
Collecting hupper>=1.5
  Using cached hupper-1.10.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting plaster-pastedeploy
  Using cached plaster_pastedeploy-0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.8 kB)
Collecting zope.interface>=3.8.0
  Using cached zope.interface-5.4.0.tar.gz (249 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting venusian>=1.0
  Using cached venusian-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting translationstring>=0.4
  Using cached translationstring-1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting pbkdf2
  Using cached pbkdf2-1.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting markupsafe
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (17 kB)
Collecting jinja2!=2.11.0,!=2.11.1,!=2.11.2,>=2.5.0
  Using cached Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting transaction>=2.0
  Using cached transaction-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
Collecting greenlet!=0.4.17
  Using cached greenlet-1.1.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (101 kB)
Collecting PasteDeploy>=2.0
  Using cached PasteDeploy-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: cryptacular, pyramid-filterwarnings, zope.interface
  Building wheel for cryptacular (pyproject.toml) ... done
  WARNING: Building wheel for cryptacular failed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Meir Israeli\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-lnvsxd9w\\cryptacu
lar-1.6.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl'
  Building wheel for pyramid-filterwarnings (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for pyramid-filterwarnings: filename=pyramid_filterwarnings-0.4-py3-none-any.whl size=3751 sha256=8c8c99a9acb034a282fabc0d76d0dc0aa5eda94845fdce3d7
a19cb7e34c2e934
  Stored in directory: c:\users\meir israeli\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\83\8c\6b\c3b2da1653b88af98992da7f4774d7907450706d4d1dff3298
  Building wheel for zope.interface (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for zope.interface: filename=zope.interface-5.4.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl size=211254 sha256=d6735f1745a8f576611ae0689f0a590e336212133aaf517d554e
e3682a605080
  Stored in directory: c:\users\meir israeli\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\21\a9\8b\0bfc5594d8e109d5b25d6b69e0cff14d09d93e3522dcb16d2b
Successfully built pyramid-filterwarnings zope.interface
Failed to build cryptacular
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptacular, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda, you can try `conda install cryptacular` before installing `apex`.